# Update a field with a cascaded string, depending on other fields

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL query (simplified):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Phone1 = 049
    ,Phone2 = 123
    ,Class = --???
WHERE Project = 'ABC'
```

So I just want to set some default values for every project 'ABC'. For the Class field I want the following: There are 5 other fields in the table, Class1 to Class5, each field contains a 1 or a 0. If Class1 is 1, then Class should contain "C1". If Class1 and Class3 contain a 1, then Class should be "C1 + C3". If all ClassN fields contain a 1 it should be "C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5" and so on.

Now that's not too hard either:

```
DECLARE @Class NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Class1 INT = 0
DECLARE @Class2 INT = 0
DECLARE @Class3 INT = 0
DECLARE @Class4 INT = 0
DECLARE @Class5 INT = 0

SET @Class = CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(@Class1, 0) = 1
            THEN 'C1 + '
        ELSE ''
        END
SET @Class = ISNULL(@Class, '') + CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(@Class2, 0) = 1
            THEN 'C2 + '
        ELSE ''
        END
SET @Class = ISNULL(@Class, '') + CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(@Class3, 0) = 1
            THEN 'C3 + '
        ELSE ''
        END
SET @Class = ISNULL(@Class, '') + CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(@Class4, 0) = 1
            THEN 'C4 + '
        ELSE ''
        END
SET @Class = ISNULL(@Class, '') + CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(@Class5, 0) = 1
            THEN 'C5 + '
        ELSE ''
        END

-- Remove last +
IF (LEN(@Class) > 0)
    SET @Class = LEFT(ISNULL(@Class, ''), LEN(@Class) - 2)

SELECT @Class
```

But now I am just not sure how to combine those two things the best way. How can I combine them the best way?

My best idea right now is to create a scalar-valued function and return the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Phone1 = 049
    ,Phone2 = 123
    ,Class = 
CASE WHEN 1 IN (Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4, Class5) THEN
LEFT(
CONCAT(
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class1, 0) = 1 THEN 'C1 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class2, 0) = 1 THEN 'C2 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class3, 0) = 1 THEN 'C3 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class4, 0) = 1 THEN 'C4 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class5, 0) = 1 THEN 'C5 + ' ELSE '' END
)
, LEN(
CONCAT(
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class1, 0) = 1 THEN 'C1 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class2, 0) = 1 THEN 'C2 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class3, 0) = 1 THEN 'C3 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class4, 0) = 1 THEN 'C4 + ' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Class5, 0) = 1 THEN 'C5 + ' ELSE '' END
)
) - 2)
ELSE '' END 
WHERE Project = 'ABC'
```

Comment: @Feroc Don't worry that there is the same `CONCAT` block twice, it will only be executed once. The optimizer does a good job. Any feedback?

Comment: Thanks, that should work nice. Now I am just thinking if a function is the cleaner solution.